# Can an AC magnetic field be measured by a hall probe?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, measurements, measurement-problem

Many hall sensors on the market have a datasheet that explain the proportional relationship between the analog voltage that is outputted and the relative gauss/tesla reading (for example: 2.5mV = 1Gauss). How would one go about selectively measuring AC fields in the same manner with for example this Hall effect sensor: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9312 . Is it even possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: "AC" is vague, it could be 0.01 Hz or it could be 1 THz. What frequency range are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve said, you need to specify the frequency you're looking for. That's because any apparatus will have a given temporal response, which determines what time-scale you can resolve. For example, the response of the probe you cited is of the order of the microsecond according to the component details. If the field is oscillating faster than that, then you will not see the oscillations. This sets the maximum frequency at about 1 MHz, which is way higher than the usual 50 Hz or 100 Hz of AC currents in a household.

Comment: OK, I understand. I would like to measure in the 40 Hz — 100 Hz range with a resolution of 0.01 µT

Comment: Then it should be OK according to my answer. For more details, you may want to ask the question on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll post another question on electronics.stackexchange for the actual "implementation".